std::mutex error when compiling for RPi Pico (CMake)
I have been looking at this problem for a few days now and cannot seem to find the answer in any online forums/ document.
This is what I'm doing: I have a RPi 3B connected via USB to a RPi Pico (actually it's not connected yet but that's irrelevant, I'm just building the binaries for now). I SSH with my computer to the 3B, and have all of the project stored in that device.
I'm using cmake to compile and run everything. After typing cmake .. , I then type sudo make VERBOSE=1
Overview of file structure:
PovGlobe
|--depes
|--build
|--cpp_src
|--...

Here is a snapshot of the CMakeLists.txt in the PovGlobe (parent) directory:
CMakeLists.text:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

set(PICO_SDK_FETCH_FROM_GIT on)

set(PICO_SDK_PATH "/home/nicoc/PovGlobe/depes/pico-sdk")
include(/home/nicoc/PovGlobe/depes/pico-sdk/pico_sdk_init.cmake)

project(PovGlobe)

set(EXT_DIR ./ext)
set(PICO_SDK_FETCH_FROM_GIT on)
set(PYTHON_LIBRARIES "/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpython3.11.so")
set(PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS "/usr/include/python3.11")


pico_sdk_init()

set(CORE_LIB_NAME ${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}_core_lib)
set(HW_LIB_EXT_NAME ${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}_hw_lib_ext)
set(SIM_LIB_EXT_NAME ${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}_sim_lib_ext)
set(APPS_LIB_NAME ${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}_apps_lib)

set(PY_WRAPPER_LIB_NAME Py${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME})

set(EXEC_MAIN_NAME ${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME})

if(NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)
  set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)
endif()

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
...

(I excluded extra lines i think were not relevant)
After running the sudo make VERBOSE=1, the compilator starts but ends with this error (mentions the error two times actually as I use mutex two times):
Console out:
[ 50%] Building CXX object cpp_src/PovGlobe/sim/CMakeFiles/PovGlobe_sim_lib_ext.dir/renderer_sim.cpp.obj
cd /home/nicoc/PovGlobe/build/cpp_src/PovGlobe/sim && /usr/bin/arm-none-eabi-g++ -DSIM_AVAILABLE  -Wall -Wextra -O3 -std=gnu++14 -MD -MT cpp_src/PovGlobe/sim/CMakeFiles/PovGlobe_sim_lib_ext.dir/renderer_sim.cpp.obj -MF CMakeFiles/PovGlobe_sim_lib_ext.dir/renderer_sim.cpp.obj.d -o CMakeFiles/PovGlobe_sim_lib_ext.dir/renderer_sim.cpp.obj -c /home/nicoc/PovGlobe/cpp_src/PovGlobe/sim/renderer_sim.cpp
(skipping warnings)
/home/nicoc/PovGlobe/cpp_src/PovGlobe/sim/../core/globe.hpp:9:1: note: 'std::mutex' is defined in header '<mutex>'; did you forget to '#include <mutex>'?
    8 | #include "helper.hpp"
  +++ |+#include <mutex>
    9 | #include <mutex>
/home/nicoc/PovGlobe/cpp_src/PovGlobe/sim/../core/globe.hpp:69:10: error: 'mutex' in namespace 'std' does not name a type
   69 |     std::mutex m_double_buffer_mutex;
      |          ^~~~~
/home/nicoc/PovGlobe/cpp_src/PovGlobe/sim/../core/globe.hpp:69:5: note: 'std::mutex' is defined in header '<mutex>'; did you forget to '#include <mutex>'?
   69 |     std::mutex m_double_buffer_mutex;
      |     ^~~

You can even see during the traceback that mutex is already included (and even then it suggests including it again)
There are two hpp files that use sdt::mutex and both of them throw the error in almost the extact same way.
Is there a problem with my compiler? Should i add another library to the CMake file?
Thanks a lot everyone.
I investigated some time but I was not able to find any information regarding the subject.

#include "helper.hpp is on line 8 and #include <mutex> is on line 9 which is after the include that uses it.  Always try and include standard header files first.

@RichardCritten thanks for the warning. I added the include at that point so that it shows in the traceback, but even when written correctly at the beginning, it still produces the error.

This is the beginning of globe.hpp:

#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
#include <mutex>
#include "renderer_base.hpp"
#include "application_base.hpp"
#include "framebuffer.hpp"
#include "helper.hpp"```

Looking for the answer myself, I found a post on the raspberry pi forum that said the C++ standard library isn't supported on the pico. It sounds like your best bet is using the pico_sync API that has mutexes and semaphores.
